# Laravel save($request->all()) Error

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a question, I've been developing laravel application and I encountered this strange error:

```html
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testenv`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_tenant_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tenant_id`) REFERENCES `tenants` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `products` () values ())
```

and Here's my store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product;

    /*
    $product->name = $request->name;
    $product->stockQty = $request->stockQty;
    $product->minimumQty = $request->minimumQty;
    $product->description = $request->description;
    $product->notes = $request->notes;
    $product->tenantMargin = $request->tenantMargin;
    $product->length = $request->length;
    $product->height = $request->height;
    $product->weight = $request->weight;
    $product->showLength = $request->showLength;
    $product->showHeight = $request->showHeight;
    $product->showWeight = $request->showWeight;
    $product->size = $request->size;
    $product->colorName = $request->colorName;
    $product->colorHex = $request->colorHex;
    $product->isActive =$request->isActive;
    $product->tenant_id = $request->tenant_id;
    $product->productviewid = $request->productviewid;
    */

    $product->save($request->all());

    return "product successfully created";
}
```

And the error only occurs if i use

`$product->save($request->all());`

but if I un-comment the the commented code and use

`$product->save()`

instead, it works, no error.

Can anyone help me to find the source of this problem?

Comment: use only $product->save()

Comment: you are saving everything twice. Once one by one , and the second time Everything at once (second is better). But with the second approach you need to add fillable fields to your model

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you're not using the [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature, you should use `$product->save();` here.

If you want to use the mass assignment, just do this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Product::create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Yes This is it, the mass assignment feature, It works now, thank you very much!

Comment: How can I do this? $request->product->all(); If I am receiving data in an object format,

Answer (score 3):

As Alexey said, `$product->save()`it's going to use the data sent in the function instead of whatever you've set before, just like what you are trying to do in your example.

That way you are *not* using the mass assignment feature, because you are specifying every single field that needs to be updated in the database.

`$product->save($parameters)` actually makes use of the mass assignment feature and those attributes need to fillable, or un-guarded in the laravel properties.

Note that also `Model::create()` supports mass assignments.